# TKinter ListBox item height

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to shrink the height of the cells of TKinter listbox at initialization?

```
self.lb = Listbox(f,selectmode=MULTIPLE, bd=1, height=10)
self.lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.onSelectlbItem)
self.lb.grid(row=3, column=1,columnspan=7, sticky="WE", pady=0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The height of the rows in a tkinter listbox is dependent on the size of the text font.  This can be set for the whole widget (although not for individual rows), either as the `font=` optional argument at initialization, or using the `.config` method of the listbox post-initiatlization.

Below is how the code might look if you do the font-size setting at initialization time:

```
import tkFont
small_font = tkFont.Font(size=5) # Specify font size, and use default style for other parameters

self.lb = Listbox(f,selectmode=MULTIPLE, bd=1, height=10, font=small_font)
```

**Edit** The above example is for Python 2.  If you are using Python 3, I believe the correct way to import/use the font utilities is now `from tk import font` and `small_font = font.Font(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

The height of the rows do depend on the font size, but there is an easier way to change the font size without the need to import anything:

```
self.lb = Listbox(f,selectmode=MULTIPLE, bd=1, height=10, font=('Times', 14))
```